# What is the term for overloading to cover optional parameters

Tags: overloading

Is there a term for the technique of overloading to create optional parameters? "Helper Method" comes to mind but doesn't seem appropriate

```
foo(var x)
{
    foo(x, new var());
}

foo(var x, var y);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called overloading.